# Register multiple sidebars

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am registering my sidebars as follows:

```
$sidebars = array (
            'sidebar-10'       => 'Main Sidebar',
            'sidebar-11'       => 'Homepage Area One',
            'sidebar-12'       => 'Homepage Area Two',
            'sidebar-13'       => 'Homepage Area Three',
            'sidebar-14'       => 'Homepage Area Four',
            'sidebar-15'       => 'Footer Area One',
            'sidebar-16'       => 'Footer Area Two',
            'sidebar-17'       => 'Footer Area Three',
            'sidebar-18'       => 'Footer Area Four',
            'sidebar-19'       => 'After first post area',
            'sidebar-20'       => 'Below header area',
            );
foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ) {
register_sidebar(
    array (
            'name'          => __( $sidebar, 'pietergoosen' ),
            'id'            => $sidebar,
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ));
}
```

`Main Sidebar` is the name of my widget. I need to set `sidebar-10` as the widget id. The same with the rest as in my array.

Any suggestions solving this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the alternate syntax for foreach.  From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
>   foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
>   you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
>   uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

For your example:

```
foreach ( $sidebars as $id => $sidebar) {
register_sidebar(
    array (
            'name'          => __( $sidebar, 'pietergoosen' ),
            'id'            => $id,
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, happy coding.

Comment: Andrew, is there a way of doing this if you have three variables? I scratched around in the php manual, but got no wiser. The thing is, I'm still a newby in php. As above, if I add the description of the sidebar to the array of the name and id like this " 'name' => 'id' => 'description' ", will it work, does php and more so, Wordpress, allow this.

Comment: Foreach loops over a key => value pair.  You can set the value to an array to store multiple values, like the description and the name if necessary by creating nested arrays when you originally build the $sidebars array.

Comment: If it is possible please, can you give me an example of how to do it. I'm a bit new at this

Comment: i got it working. Seems like I'm getting php coding. Here is my code. http://pastebin.com/83ikqdk6